# Need output to revert to original text when criteria not met

Tags: java, debugging, output

My program crashes when "charAt(0)" is not in "u", "l", "e", "o" or a number. Any ideas how to get it to output original text in any other instances, e.g. "charAt(0)="q"?

Sample of code is included:
                // Includes text letters of length of initial text being an integer

```
    } else { int num = Character.getNumericValue(first.charAt(0)); 
        String str = ""; 
        for(int i = 0;i < num;i++){ 
            str += first.charAt(i); 
        }

        first = str;

    }

    System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + first);
}
```

}
When I run this the program it just crashes.

Comment: can you share your full code?

Comment: Code is too long but will try put on now.

Comment: Full code included now. Just when any other instance is put in for chatAt(0) I need the output to be original text, not an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your else block with the following block and try.

```
    } else {    
        String str = "";        
        if(Character.isDigit(first.charAt(0))){
            int num = Character.getNumericValue(first.charAt(0));               
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                str += first.charAt(i);
            }
        }else{
            for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i++) {
                str += first.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        first = str;
    }
```

Comment: That does it! Thanks so much.